# Best practices for deploying AWS worker application with SQS queue for asynchronous tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, worker, aws-code-deploy

I am running an AWS EC2 server and have a worker application.
The worker application uses AWS SQS queue to perform asynchronous background tasks.

What are the best practices for deploying the worker application?
I understand that blue/green deployment can block traffic during the deployment process, but I don't think the part of the application that polls the SQS queue will be blocked.

The concern is that the worker application may be processing data until the old server is about to shut down and the application is terminated.
I'm not sure how to handle this situation.

Comment: The beauty of SQS is that if your application does not explicitly delete a message within a certain timeframe to indicate that it processed it successfully, then that message will reappear in the SQS queue. It's called [visibility timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html).

Comment: @jarmod Thank you. As you suggested, I think there should be no problem as I only delete the message when the task is fully completed and successful. I just need to check if there is any logic in my code that polls and deletes messages immediately. Additionally, I need to make sure that the same message is not processed repeatedly to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Be aware of CodeDeploy [AppSpec hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html) for lifecycle event hooks.